# django: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to add a PasswordChangeForm into my project, but i gean error:

> "**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'"

How can i fix it?
My View:

```
def password_change_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if pass_form.is_valid():
        pass_form.save()
        return redirect('users/login')
else:
    pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, 'users/change_password.html', {'password_form': pass_form})
```

and my html file:

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %} Изменение пароля {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="user_content">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ password_form.as_p }}
        <center><button type="submit">Сохранить</button></center>
    </form></div>
{% endblock %}
```

I think, my mistake is somewhere in view, but i cant find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PasswordChangeForm` is not a `ModelForm` but a `Form` instead. Looking at its `__init__` method it is declared as:

> ```
> def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
>     ...
> ```

Meaning you need to pass the user as either the first positional argument or as a keyword argument. So your view should be:

```
def password_change_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if pass_form.is_valid():
            pass_form.save()
            return redirect('users/login')
    else:
        pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'users/change_password.html', {'password_form': pass_form})
```